# Lassen Sie es mich nochmal probieren. Location of 'es'

Tags: objects

I see in a German language book this statement.
A: Lassen Sie es mich nochmal probieren.
But to me,
B: Lassen Sie mich es nochmal probieren.
sounds more natural.
Is only A correct? If not, is A more widely used than B?

Having asked that(on second thought), I guess both are correct but with different nuance.
A : (there are more than two candidate persons who can test it but) please let "me" test it one more time(not other person, emphasis on me).
B : (We don't know if there are other people but) let me just test it one more time.
Am I not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both A and B are correct. German is pretty open towards creative word order.

I can't really make out a preference between the two - both would fit fine to both your example cases - the difference you suspect will only become obvious by putting an *audible accent* on "mich" - but still in both examples.

Comment: Even though B is correct, A sounds more natural to me (native speaker).

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf I was thinking about that first as well. But depending on where you puit the accent on when speaking, they are actually equal. (B sounds perfectly fine to me when someone tried to open a door and didn't succeed and you propose to try it for them - with an accent on "mich", and maybe without the "es")